# How to trace ChangePassword of authentication in API

Tags: authentication, asp.net-web-api, postman

I have an API which dose not any related View and it's for authentication's methods, my change password has been doing something wrong, I don't know what's the exact problem then I have to trace it

My change password is :

```
        [Route("password")]
        [BasicAuthenticationFilter]
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<UpdateResult<bool>> ChangePassword([FromBody]ChangePasswordViewModel password)
        {
            try
            {
                var result = await _userManagerService.ChangePassword(Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name, password.NewPassword, password.OldPassword);
                return UpdateResult<bool>.Success(result);
                var ChangePasswordViewModel = new ChangePasswordViewModel { OldPassword = "", NewPassword = "" };
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return UpdateResult<bool>.Fail(ex.Message, 1);
            }
        }
```

Because it's httpPost I'm using PostMan to trace it and my url is like this :

```
http://localhost:2511/v1/auth/password?password=new ChangePasswordViewModel{ OldPassword = "13532548", NewPassword = "123456" }
```

But it send my password parameter null, What's my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specified that your parameters should be passed in your request body by using [FromBody] attribute like this `[FromBody]ChangePasswordViewModel password` then this URL

```
http://localhost:2511/v1/auth/password?password=new ChangePasswordViewModel{ OldPassword = "13532548", NewPassword = "123456" }
```

is incorrect for passing data to your action. With Postman, you should do this if you want to reach your action:

[image]

Second just because you're using basic authentication then make sure to give the authentication data to Postamn too like this:

[image]